# Who is the "winner" of each leg of a two-legged football match, or a match that goes to penalties?

Tags: football, world-cup, betting, europa-league

#### Match #1

[Europa League, quarter-finals, 2nd leg](https://www.uefa.com/uefaeuropaleague/season=2017/matches/round=2000795/match=2019697/index.html): After 90 minutes Besiktas was up 2-1 against Lyon. Because of the aggregate score of 3-3 ([Lyon won 2-1 in the 1st leg](https://www.uefa.com/uefaeuropaleague/season=2017/matches/round=2000795/match=2019693/index.html)) they had to play extra time and then use penalty shootout to decide who got to go on in the to the semi-final. Lyon won on penalties.

#### Match #2

[World Cup, round of 16](https://www.fifa.com/worldcup/matches/match/300331517/#match-liveblog): After 90 minutes the score was 1-1 between Spain and Russia. To get a winner they had to play extra time and do a penalty shootout. Russia won on penalties.

#### Questions

1. Which teams are considered the **winner** of the two **single matches**? (What I'm really wondering about is if that penalty shootout in a two-legged match is considered to be part of that single match or not.)
2. In a team form view of the team would you expect to see Lyon to have won or lost the last match? (Would you be able to say that Besiktas or Spain have not lost any of their X matches because of the full-time score?)

Comment: It might be helpful if you explained why this was important to you - I can see it is for betting purposes, but the answer is then "talk to your bookie". Other than that, it doesn't matter who won the two single Europa League matches, Lyon won the tie and went through; similarly for the World Cup, Russia went through, nothing else matters.

Comment: The question came up in regards of representing the team form graphically + having facts like "Team X has not lost in Y matches". But it also got more philosophically. There must some sort of rule/law/definition of this. I was unable to find anything about this in FIFA's rules.

Comment: Usually for an statistics porpuosse, the winner or loser of the match is the one that made it outside of the penalty shootout. Once a match reach that phase, is only a matter of who goes to the next round, but the result is the real one in full time

Comment: Statistical analysis is not usually part of the rules (US major sports being an absurd exception in some cases). FIFA certainly doesn't care about individual matches as part of a tie, only the end result according to max-total-goals/max-away-goals/KFTPM.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Laws of the Game ([2 Mb pdf-file](https://www.fifa.com/mm/Document/FootballDevelopment/Refereeing/02/36/01/11/LawsofthegamewebEN_Neutral.pdf)):

> **Winning team**
>
> The team scoring the greater number of goals during a match is the
> winner. If both teams score an equal number of goals, or if no goals
> are scored, the match is drawn.
>
> **Competition rules**
>
> When competition rules require there to be a winning team after a match or home-and-away tie, the only permitted
> procedures for determining the winning team are those approved by the
> International F.A. Board, namely:
>
> - away goals rule
> - extra time
> - kicks from the penalty mark

Based on that penalty shootout is considered to be a part of a single play-off game. However, it is not clear whether penalty shootout can be considered as a part of the second match in a home-and-away tie.

So

1. The winner if every single match in 2-legs game is the team who scored the greater number of goals.
2. However, it is not defined who is the winner of the second leg in a home-and-away tie situation if it comes to penalty shootout. It's only defined who is the winner of the whole stage.

Comment: Take in mind, that the winner is not the one who has more goals.. in this case: A 2-1 B, and B 3-2 A, the winner is A on the away goals rule.